# Electron like node integration in nodejs web server

Tags: node.js, electron, webserver

I'm new to web servers in nodejs and i'd like to know if there is possible to have an electron like node integration in a web server (to be able to use nodejs in index.js script file linked to index.html)

Thx for all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Browsers control the way that client side JavaScript is executed, so it's just technically impossible to connect both runtimes in any way that works on client machine, you'd need a customized browser, which is what Electron basically is. And neither should you want to - if the runtimes were connected in that way, any user could execute arbitrary commands on your server.